# simple_form and on the fly conversions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

I'm writing a rails app where there is a model that takes certain measures (height, weight, neck_circumference, etc.)

I want it to work both for metric and imperial measurement system.

My model has a measure_unit attribute that can be both metric or imperial. All the measures will be stored in the database in metric system.

I use the simple_form gem, and I have no clue on how to implement the views so that if a user uses the imperial system his data is converted on the fly.

```
<% if @customer.measure_unit.eql? "metric" %>                                                            
  <%= f.input :height %></br>                                
<% else %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

How do I fill the blanks?

**EDIT -- Found a working solution**

I ended up using virtual attributes such as "height_in_cm" and "height_in_in" leaving the entries in the database to be stored in mm.

Here is the code for the model:

```
  def height_in_cm
    height / 10
  end

  def height_in_cm=(height)
    self.height = height.to_f  * 10
  end

  def height_in_in
    height * 0.039370
  end

  def height_in_in=(height)
    self.height = height.to_f / 0.039370
  end
```

And the code for the view:

```
  <% if @customer.measure_unit.eql? "imperial" %>
    <%= f.input :height_in_in %></br>
  <% else %>      
    <% if @customer.measure_unit.eql? "metric" %>
      <%= f.input :height_in_cm %></br>
    <% end %>     
  <% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to pass a hidden field back to the controller indicating that the value passed is imperial and needs to be converted into metric for database storage.

So rather than having a different input for metric and imperial measurements you can simply use a single input which defaults to metric and you have to detect for the non-default (imperial):

```
<%= f.input :height %></br>                                
<%= f.hidden_field :imperial, :value => (@customer.measure_unit.eql? "imperial" ? true : false) %>
```

Now in your controller action before you have the measurement attribute saved:

```
if params[:imperial] == true
  #convert imperial measurement to metric (replace @foo with your object)
  @foo.height = convert_to_metric(params[:height]) 
end
```

Comment: Yes, this will probably work. Going to try to implement it. Thank you!

Comment: your solution looked promising, but it ended up messing the update action recalculating the conversion also for already converted measures.